# json_decode returns json string not an array

Tags: php, json, ajax

```
<?php

$json=file_get_contents('php://input',true);
$data = json_decode($json, true);

print_r($data);
?>
```

Output given is `{"EventTitle":"Game","EventBody":"body","EventDate":"20 November, 2016","EventType":"party"}`

Json Data posted is:

```
 {"EventTitle":"Game","EventBody":"body","EventDate":"20 November, 2016","EventType":"party"}
```

Writing the json data in a variable and passing it to json_decode works but posting the same  from the "php://input" returns a JSON data instead of associative array.

Comment: what does `var_dump($json)` print?

Comment: Yes, It prints this value
`string(107) ""{\"EventTitle\":\"Game\",\"EventBody\":\"body\",\"EventDate\":\"20 November, 2016\",\"EventType\":\"party\"}""`

Comment: What happens if you change `file_get_contents('php://input',true);` to `file_get_contents('php://input');`?

Comment: looks like it was encoded twice

Comment: Same Output as before `{"EventTitle":"Game","EventBody":"body","EventDate":"20 November, 2016","EventType":"party"}`

Comment: So, $json is a string, not JSON ...

Comment: Yes, The data was encoded twice in the ajax call.
It is fixed now. Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It looks like @tkausl is correct. The JSON you're receiving has been double-encoded. Since it's double-encoded, a temporary solution would be to double-decode it.

```
$data = json_decode(json_decode($json), true);
```

But the real solution is to figure out why it's like that to begin with and fix it (if it's yours to fix).